# Problem with walnut finish

Tags: finishing

A typical finish we do on walnut is staining with Old Masters Natural Walnut stain (sprayed and wiped) and then 2 coats of a waterborne poly on top.

A fabulous finish. However a couple of times we have encountered some blotchy areas after the first coat of clear is applied. Before the clear the stain looks uniform with no visible defects. These spots or areas are now devoid of the stain.

It kind of looks like some diluted glue had seeped into the grain. But if it was glue then the stain wouldn’t have taken and have been visible prior to applying the clear.

Any ideas out there or perhaps someone has seen this as well?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE. This may be something you'd be better off asking on Woodweb rather than here as there's a much larger standing membership of working pros with a wide array of finishing experience. As we would here too you'll probably be asked to provide some photos to give a clearer picture of the problem and the magnitude of it — I'm having difficulty reconciling these two sentences, *"Before the clear the stain looks uniform with no visible defects. These spots or areas are now devoid of the stain."* and at a guess I wouldn't be the only one.